# Eclipse getting shut down every time I try to open a jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, myeclipse

I am using myEclipse blue 8.6. Today when I was trying to open a jsp file it was shutting down. 
I tried to change the workspace but the problem persists.
Any help?

Comment: Are you getting any message/error ?

Comment: No, The moment u select a jsp from a package to open. The eclipse will shut down.

Comment: Goto eclipse directory and check eclipse error log file first 
check other log file inside  workspace/.metadata/  folder to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a way to install certain "add-ons" in order to accommodate features that weren't initially built into it.

- Go to the '*help*' option on your Eclipse toolbar, then click '*Eclipse MarketPlace*'. I suggest searching for a Jsp editor there, (although most that I have seen in Eclipse work quite lousy).
- Your other option is to install **Apache** (Either Apache itself or the entire **[Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)** package; I prefer this method over using Eclipse). Then place your .jsp file in **/htdocs/JSP** folder in the Apache installation section. You're going to have to name the JSP file with a .jsp extension, (i.e. **index.jsp**). Open your Apache/Xampp, then run Apache and start the web service. Click '***Start***' button to see it, then go to your browser's address bar and type in either: ***localhost/JSP/index.jsp*** or ***127.0.0.1/JSP/index.jsp*** and it should display.

Comment: myEclipse already includes a JSP-editor.  It is not a standard Eclipse distribution.

Comment: tried your suggestions. But problem seems to be something else.
I think re-install would help.